# Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED', all gas used up

Tags: solidity, transactions, revert-opcode, erc-20-approve, assert

I'm trying to buy some [CHY](https://etherscan.io/token/0x35a23bc27c345b36dee700a256f69c6334030971) with [USDT](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) on Uniswap main net, fails with `error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'`,

This is my failed [tx link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x76385c1f71dcd5453585c4344844787fe65cca0d58384d6ad8f740273e114d5a).

This is a successful [tx link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcb48985249710deb9da5b1de417c5bc76e8d95f368f3c90aecbbfd1f26a0153c) from someone else.

I notice my *transaction fee* is abnormally **high**, much higher than other successful txs, and no matter how I raise the `gasLimit`, it always used up, only takes more time.

On the page of successful tx there is [Uniswap V2: CHY-USDT](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa78ccdd0ede4079d0d8a6747555d7baf7c33931b),  which is not used in my code, is this the reason that my tx never find a correct way, but always keep finding and eat  up all the gas?

How to correct the code?

**Update 1**: add "approve()" before transacting. The "approve()" succeeded the first time, after that it never succeeded again, always fails [like this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x325cdfae442893c6dcc06517888b842a6dbca7cafa91d1da7c7b9f3c4cfc914f)

```js
const CHY = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, '0x35A23BC27c345b36DeE700a256F69C6334030971', 9)
const USDT = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7', 6)

const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(CHY, USDT)

const route = new Route([pair], USDT) // direction, from USDT -> CHY

var base = ethers.BigNumber.from(10).pow(route.path[0].decimals)
var amountIn = ethers.BigNumber.from(50).mul(base) // 50 * 10^6 == 50 USDT
console.log(amountIn.toString()) // 50 USDT

const trade = new Trade(
    route, 
    new TokenAmount(USDT, amountIn),
    TradeType.EXACT_INPUT) 


const slippageTolerance = new Percent('50', '10000') // 0.5%
const amountOutMin = trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance).raw
const path = [USDT.address, CHY.address] // <---------check direction
const to = MY_WALLET;
const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 20*60 // 20 minutes

const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('mainnet', {
    infura: INFURA_ID
})

const signer = new ethers.Wallet(MY_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY)
const account = signer.connect(provider)
const uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
    '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D', // fixed Route02.addr
    ['function swapExactTokensForTokens( uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'],
    account
)

// approve
const contract_usdt = new ethers.Contract(
    addr_usdt,
    //['function approve(address spender, uint value) public'],
    ['function approve(address spender, uint amount) public returns(bool)'],
    account
);
const tx_approve = await contract_usdt.approve(uniswap.address, amountIn, {
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    gasLimit: gasLimit
})

console.log('tx_approve: ' + tx_approve.hash);

const receipt_approve = await tx_approve.wait()
console.log(receipt_approve)


const tx = await uniswap.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    amountIn.toString(),
    amountOutMin.toString(),
    path,
    to,
    deadline,
    { 
        gasLimit: 400000,
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("40", "gwei") 
    }
)
console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`)
const receipt = await tx.wait()
```

And I tried `path=[USDT, UNIWAP_V2_CHY_USDT, CHY]`, [also fails](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0e7c54917fa5b2a89eae62f03f7fbf4bfc032cfd2163cd1112824598218f765d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You did not approve USDT to the router address before attempting the swap.**

The USDT contract uses `assert` instead of `revert` or `throw` to cancel the transaction because of the lack of approval. Using `assert` will consume all the gas left. It's bad practice by Tether to use `assert`, but it's probably because their contract is really old.

EDIT: Also, the USDT contract requires you to set the allowance to 0 before making another approve call. Here is the relevant code of the USDT contract:

```
function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) {

    // To change the approve amount you first have to reduce the addresses`
    //  allowance to zero by calling `approve(_spender, 0)` if it is not
    //  already 0 to mitigate the race condition described here:
    //  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
    require(!((_value != 0) && (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0)));

    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
}
```

Comment: Code updated with `approve()`, it succeeded the first time and never succeed again, please refer to the updated post.

Comment: See my edit, it's the USDT contract that is weird